# flutter I want to get List<int> values ​as ints one by one

Tags: flutter

I want to get List values ​​as ints one by one.

where movieId requires an int value.

help me please

thank you

```
Future<MovieDetailModel> getMovieDetail(int? movieId) async {
try {
  http.Response res = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('$mainUrl/movie/$**movieId**?$apiKey&language=ko-KR'))
      .timeout(Duration(seconds: 8),
          onTimeout: () async => new http.Response('{}', 404));

  if (res.statusCode == 404) {
    return MovieDetailModel.fromJson({});
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> result = jsonDecode(res.body);
  MovieDetailModel movies = MovieDetailModel.fromJson(result);
  return movies;
} catch (e) {
  print('MovieDetail $e');
}
return MovieDetailModel.fromJson({});
}
```

where user.userMovieId value is List .

```
Widget userMovie(UserModel user) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: this._movieDetailProvider.movies(**user.userMovieId!**),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MovieDetailModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {}
```

Provider.

```
Future<MovieDetailModel> movies(int movieId) async {
MovieDetailModel movieList = await _movieRepo.getMovieDetail(movieId);
notifyListeners();
return movieList;
```

}

Comment: I did not get your question well, but if you get only one movie from API and you extract it as a Movie class, you can call it by move.userMovieID! if you need it before API call, I think you should have an endpoint for API extraction in your server!

Comment: My purpose is to collect and show currentUser's favorite movies.

Comment: so have you ID of his/her favorite movie?

Comment: yes. Save the userMovieId to the server when you click favorite.

Comment: So, there is a list of `int` values in your DB. you can call them by an API service and look through them. If I get your means right! I am not sure about your problem though.

Comment: The api query requires an int value as Movieid.

But the usermovieid stored in my db is list<int> .

You can represent them one by one like this: usermovieId[0] or usermovieid[1] .

But what I want is to show all usermovies stored in db.

Comment: why you don't try storing all id's together by hashMap or as a JSON text? so you can restore all of them at once.